# Переключение css по клику jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, onclicklistener

Интересует переключение css по клику:
Нажал раз - сменилось,
Нажал два - вернулось то, что было.

Имеется:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.appartments-item__star').on('click', function() {  
      $(this).css({'background-image':'url(img/star-dark.png)'});   
        });
})();
```

Хотелось бы по второму клику получать назад url(img/star.png)

Везде используют классы, интересует же именно переключение по css, а не по классам.

Comment: toggle пробуйте

Comment: Я уже пробовал и так и эдак, не выходит. За jquery только взялся.

Comment: А что мешает добавить флаг в виде `true` - `false` и просто менять его когда нужно? Где например `false` - изменить картинку, а `true` - вернуть прежнюю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда вот так можно ...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#toggle-click').on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
    }

  });

});
```

```css
#toggle-click {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-click"></div>
```

Comment: Смысл все так усложнять, когда 1 переменной все решается.

Comment: @And вы можете свой вариант показать

Answer (score 5):

Можно вынести все стили отдельно, и переключать класс на элементе [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
<style>
    .some {
        background-image: url(img/star-dark.png);
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.appartments-item__star').on('click', function() {  
            $(this).toggleClass('some');   
        });
    })();
</script>
```